# How to split an integer list into two separate lists that are around the same average? -Python

Tags: python, list, integer

I have a list:

```
numbers = [1, 10, 15, 16, 64, 100, 0, 0, 0, 3]
```

And I want to split it into two lists. The two lists need to have a similar average. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partition-an-array-of-non-negative-integers-into-two-subsets-such-that-average-of-both-the-subsets-is-equal/

Comment: Do they need to be as close as possible to the same average? Or is it good enough to be within a certain threshold or range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

- compute the whole `mean`
- try all different combination of all sizes until you find one thaat mean is half the total one within a delta error
- get the unsued values
- you got 2 parts with means almost equals
- return `None` is no solution has been found with the given error delta

```
def main(values, delta=0.1):
    m = mean(values)
    for i in range(1, len(values)):
        for c in combinations(values, r=i):
            i_mean = mean(c)
            if abs(i_mean - m / 2) < delta:
                other_part = [v for v in values if v not in c]
                return c, other_part
    return None
```

Demo

```
numbers = [1, 10, 15, 16, 64, 100, 0, 0, 0, 3]
print(main(numbers, 1))      # ([10], [1, 15, 16, 64, 100, 0, 0, 0, 3])
print(main(numbers, 0.1))    # ([1, 10, 15, 16], [64, 100, 0, 0, 0, 3])
print(main(numbers, 0.01))   # None
print(main(numbers, 0.001))  # None

print(main([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 0.00001))  # ([1, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```